# const pointers vs const references in C++

Tags: c++, reference

According to the following program, I can understand that, `const` keyword at a front of a references means `Const Reference to const value`, correct?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct s
{
    int x;
};

int main(void)
{
    s a = {10}, b = {30};

    // IN POINTERS ----------------
    const s* ptrToConstValue;
    ptrToConstValue= &a;
    //ptrToConstValue->x = 30; 
    ptrToConstValue = &b;

    s* const constPtrToNonConstVaue = &a;
    constPtrToNonConstVaue->x = 40;
    //constPtrToNonConstVaue = &b;

    const s* const constPtrToConstValue = &a;
    //constPtrToConstValue = &b;
    //constPtrToConstValue->x = 30;


    // IN REFERENCES -------------
    const s& seemsToBeConstRefToConstValue = a;
    //s = b;
    //s.x = 30;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you will, it's always parsed as "`(const T)&`", and never as "`const (T&)`".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

References are always const, so you don't need the `const` keyword for 
them; it is, in fact, forbidden.

So you have:

```
S*                ps;   //  Non-const pointer to a non-const value
S const*          psc;  //  Non-const pointer to a const value
S* const          pcs;  //  Const pointer to a non-const value
S const* const    pcsc; //  Const pointer to a const value
```

, but only:

```
S&                rs;   //  (const) reference to a non-const value
S const&          rsc;  //  (const) reference to a const value
```

The `const` which immediately follows the name of the type can be moved
to the beginning of the declaration, at the cost of some confusion to
the reader.

Comment: Strangely the whole moving the const to follow the type confuses me. I guess it is because it seems to be a coding style that has appeared more recently than when I was taught. I am used to seeing const R& and I would argue it is this style that is the more common. However I can see why your style above is more understandable as it follows the right-to-left way of reading things

Comment: @Firedragon The motivation behind it is two-fold.  First, of course, that in most cases, you have no choice: the `const` must follow what is const.  The second is what happens with `typedef`: if you have something like `typedef char* pc;`, and write `const pc`, what is const.  I too first saw `const` to the left when it was legal; it's the typedef argument which convinced me.

Answer (score 19):

So the confusion is this:

```
X x;

X* px       = &x; // pointer to x
X* const px  = &x; // *const pointer* to x

const X* px   = &x; // pointer to *const x*
X const* px   = &x; // identical

const X* const px = &x; // *const pointer* to *const x*
```

Now in reference, the 'pointer part' is always const:

```
X& rx = x;       // ref to x

X const& rx = x; // ref to const x
const X& rx = x; // identical
```

Answer (score 6):

References cannot be changed, after they've been initialized. So it doesn't make sense to talk about a "const reference". The reference pretty much **is** the value, and in cases like these the value is constant and cannot be changed, either.

Comment: "References cannot be changed afeter they have been initialized" , what are you talking aboug?  This compiles just fine: void bar(Box& a) {
    a.data = 33;
    a = Box(100);
}

Answer (score 6):

Yes, `const` in front of a reference means that the object referenced through it is treated as const (i.e. you can't access non-const methods or data members).

The reference itself is always "const" anyway in the sense that you can't modify it to reference a different object once it has been initialized.

Comment: Maybe "value" is a better word than "object" here?

Answer (score 4):

A reference is neither const nor non-const, it is just a reference. You can't change the referee of a reference (that's its reason d'etre), so talking about constness makes no sense. In your example, the reference is just called a const reference because its refers to a const type.

Answer (score 4):

> const keyword at a front of a references means Const Reference to const value, correct?

It means you cannot change the object *using* the reference.

The object which reference is referring to, could still be modifiable, but it cannot be modified *using* the reference:

- If the object which it refers to, is really modifiable, then you can cast away the const-ness using `const_cast` and then modify the object.
- But if the object is unmodifiable, then attempting to modify it by casting away the const-ness, would invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: +1 for "_using_ the reference", the other answers make it seem like the object itself suddenly becomes constant just because you take a `const` reference.